# text and image positioning

Tags: html, css, position

I was making a project and have to make a small website.
I want to place an image on the left and text to the right of the image.
[image: The text is always placed downwards]

I want to place the text *Car Rental* next to the car logo. how do I do that?
Html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class=banner style="width:500px;height:500px;">
        <img src="http://pattiengineering.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/
        icon-compact-car.png"
        alt="Car-Rental"style="width:500px;height:400px;">
        <p id="logo-text">Car Rental</p>

    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
body{
  background-color:black;
}

.banner {
  position:relative;
  margin:12em;  
 }

img {
  z-index:-1;
  float:left;
}

#logo-text {
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Align text to right as follows:

```
#logo-text {
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tdk6qhsd/7/)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have inline styles for `<section>`, consider moving them to CSS if you need them.
2. Cause of style to section where you make `width:500px;` You don't have enough space for the text.
3. You need also to give text `float: left`, so it will move to the right of the image

Final code:

**HTML:**

```
<section class="banner">
  <img src="http://pattiengineering.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/icon-compact-car.png" alt="Car-Rental" style="width:500px;height:400px;">
  <p id="logo-text">Car Rental</p>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color:black;
}

.banner { 
  position:relative; 
  margin:12em;
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  z-index:-1;
  float:left;
}

#logo-text {
  color:white;
  float: left;
  padding: 160px 100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Reduce the image from 500px to 400px,

and add css

```
#logo-text {
                color: white;
                float: left;
                margin-top: 12em;
            }
```

Try the below code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>         
            body {
                background-color: black;
            }
            .banner {
                margin: 12em;
                position: relative;
            }
            img {
                float: left;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            #logo-text {
                color: white;
                float: left;
                margin-top: 12em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class=banner style="width:500px;height:500px;">
            <img src="http://pattiengineering.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/
            icon-compact-car.png"
            alt="Car-Rental"style="width:400px;height:400px;">
            <p id="logo-text">Car Rental</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```